# I want to request multiple page names and page photos from the facebook api

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask, request

So im trying to request all the names and all the links to the photo from the facebook api.
But I keep getting an error because async task is already running.

```
public void getPages(){
     AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> GL = j.new GetLikes().execute(extras.getString("PIC"));

        try {
            likes = GL.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    for(int i=0;i<Json.PI;i++){
         final int j = i;
    final Request photo = new Request(
            null,
            "/" + PhotoId,
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

                    try {
                        PageInfo[j][1] = (String) jsonObject.get("picture");

                        Log.i("PICTURE", PageInfo[j][1]);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                }
            }
        );

    final Request photos = new Request(
            null,
            "/"+PageId+"/photos/uploaded",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(0);
                        Log.i("PHOTOID", (String) object.get("id"));
                        PhotoId = (String) object.get("id");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("PNAME", String.valueOf(response));

                    photo.executeAsync();

                }
            }
        );

    Request PageID = new Request(
            null,
            "/"+PageId,
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

                    try {
                        PageInfo[j][0] = jsonObject.getString("name");

                        Log.i("PNAME", PageInfo[j][0]);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    photos.executeAsync();

                }

            }
        );
    PageID.executeAsync();

     }


}
```

I'm sure im doing this all wrong, how should I be approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Request req = new Request(
session,
"/{page-id}/feed",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new Request.Callback(){
public void onCompleted(Response response) {

               try
        {    
            GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
            JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
            JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );
            String name = " ";
            String picture = " ";

            for ( int i = (arr.length()-1); i >=0; i-- )
            {
                JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject( i );


                name   = json_obj.getString( "name");
                picture = json_obj.getString("picture");
                //...

            }
            txtMessage.setText(name);
            //imgFeed is ImageView


            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(picture).into(imgFeed);

        }
        catch ( Throwable t )
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
});req.executeAsync();
```

This will get name and image from the post on wall...also remember to download the picasso lib and add it in your project.

hope this helps